# How to use a vector icon for the Android home screen with Cordova?

Tags: android, cordova

Since Android API 21 Android should allow SVGs as icons for the home screen. But as I read, it is necessary to convert the SVGs in Android Studio into vectordrawings, which are actually XML files with all SVG elements that have been converted into paths and some special tags.
To use a customized PNG icon for the homescreen, I normally saved it in a res folder and added the following line to the cordova-config.xml file (which works):

```
<platform name="android">
   <icon src="res/path/symbol.png" />
</platform>
```

To use a vector icon I‘ve tried an icon as svg and a vectordrawings version (which both hasn‘t worked).

Cordova-config-entry for SVG:

```
<platform name="android">
   <icon src="res/path/symbol.svg" />
</platform>
```

Cordova-config-entry for vectordrawing:

```
<platform name="android">
   <icon src="res/path/symbol.xml" />
</platform>
```

I couldn't found anything in the internet which deals explicit with cordova and vector-homescreen-icons. I'm thankful for any suggestion.

Edit (added the resulting AndroidManifest.xml-file):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:versionCode="10000"
android:versionName="1.0.0"
android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
package="de.myapp.app">

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="19"
    android:targetSdkVersion="27" />

<supports-screens
    android:anyDensity="true"
    android:smallScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:resizeable="true"
    android:xlargeScreens="true" />

<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<application
    android:label="@ref/0x7f030001"
    android:icon="@ref/0x7f020000"
    android:debuggable="true"
    android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
    android:supportsRtl="true">

    <activity
        android:theme="@ref/0x01030129"
        android:label="@ref/0x7f030000"
        android:name="de.myapp.app.MainActivity"
        android:launchMode="1"
        android:configChanges="0x4b4"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="0x10">

        <intent-filter
            android:label="@ref/0x7f030002">

            <action
                android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category
                android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to convert `SVG` to a `VectorDrawable`, in order to use it as a launcher icon ...there also is a [Vector Asset Studio](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/vector-asset-studio).
for example, it looks about like this (one can simply paste the `SVG`'s paths into there, only the numerical notation of the path coordinates might require minor syntax-fixing):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<vector
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="24dp"
    android:height="24dp"
    android:viewportWidth="24"
    android:viewportHeight="24">

    <path
        android:fillColor="#000000"
        android:pathData="..." />

</vector>
```

Comment: I've tried it with a VectorDrawable (which I've created with Android Studio). But unfortunately it doesn't work. Do you know if it works with Cordova?  Is my VectorDrawable integration correct? Maybe I'm making a mistake.

Comment: @selcox this is not really specific to Cordova, which is nothing but a customized Chrome `WebView` ...ever tried placing the `XML` into `res/drawable/symbol.xml` (which I'd assume is rather the correct path, as the Android SDK expects it)? it's difficult to tell what is wrong, unless having seen the vector's `XML` and also the `Manifest.xml`, which Cordova generates from `cordova-config.xml`.

Comment: I have added the resulting AndroidManifest.xml-file to my question above. The VectorDrawable is very similar to your example.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design_adaptive since API 26 even adaptive icons are being supported, vector icons since API 21... `android:icon="@ref/0x7f020000"` (resId `2130837504`) should somehow point towards resource `R.drawable.symbol` (commonly one would write it alike `android:icon="@drawable/symbol"`) ...can you see the icon, when using it elsewhere in some other Android  SDK application?

Comment: Unfortunately I’m not so familiar with native android apps. My vectordrawable is shown in the preview of Android Studio. As far as I can see Cordova builds with node.js/Grunt the settings to start android-sdk via cli to compile an apk. You say, you would expect something like “android:icon="@drawable/symbol” in the AndroidManifest. Therefore I guess the problem is not my vectordrawable, but Cordova itself which probably doesn't write the right settings for using vectordrawables. I'll try to analyse what Cordova does. Finding an answer, I'll post the solution. Thanx for help.